# Use of undeclared type "WebSocketDelegate" on device only

Tags: ios, swift, sockets, frameworks

I am using the Starscream framework and I get "Use of undeclared type 'WebSocketDelegate'" when I run on a device but not on the simulator.

```
class LoginController: UIViewController, FBSDKLoginButtonDelegate, WebSocketDelegate {
```